# How can I testfor a named entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to `testfor` a Zombie called "Zombie Boss". I've tried this:

```
/testfor @e[Name=Zombie_Boss,r=10000] ~ ~ ~
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The `name` argument shoudn't be capitalized, and also unless you are testing for the mob in a specific area, `r` argument isn't required, nor the `~`s

Try this:

```
/testfor @e[name=Zombie_Boss]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's 1.20.1 now, and `testfor` isn't a command anymore; the real command is:

```
/execute if entity @e[name=YOURE_NAME] positioned as @e[name=YOURE_NAME] run /any command
```

What I did here is test for an entity called `YOURE_NAME`, and if it exists, it turns `~ ~ ~` instead of the command block's position, it happens at the entity's position. The run is so you can write a command for what you want to do with the entity, like set a block underneath it or summon more of that entity. Just have fun with it. That's all that matters. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
/testfor @e[type=Zombie,Name=Zombie_Boss]
```

You need to place a comparator and then a repeater leading into a command block with the command.

Answer (score -1):

```
/testfor @e {CustomName:"Zombie Boss"}
```

Comment: It should also work